# Wordpress theme & site not loading after moving files

Tags: php, templates, file-manager

I was recently created a custom application for wordpress. So while doing so in my file manager (I use the one provided by godaddy(my webhost)), I moved all the files from the [DOCUMENT_ROOT] ... the webroot /public_html/ page to a seperate folder (that was 3 days ago)... 3 days later. When I moved them back, my wordpress site broke or something, and all my content (blog posts and site template) are gone, it doesn't even load my wp-login properly.

This is my website: www.security-shell.com

Before the change it looked perfectly fine, and everything was spectacular, but now it doesn't load at all, and looks like that. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks again, anyways, much appreciated

Sincerly,
D4RK_Phox

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot login, use FTP or the file manager to edit `wp-config.php` and `define` [`WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL`,](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php).

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.security-shell.com '); 
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.security-shell.com ' );
```

When you moved files to that subfolder, you [probably copied and edited the main `index.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). Make sure that that process gets reversed.

That should get things working again.

Comment: That fixed it, but what about my theme that I previously had, and all my blog posts?

Comment: Your posts are in the database and so long as you connect to the same database it doesn't matter where the PHP files are. If your database is gone you have much bigger problems and need to contact your host. Your theme files should have moved along with everything else. If you made a mistake there and don't have backups those files may be gone for good.

Comment: Everything is there in the database, but how would I go about setting it back to how it was before?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress still thinks it's being hosted in the sub-directory "/wordpress" instead of the root directory. To fix this.

- Sign into your admin here (http://security-shell.com/wp-login.php)
- Once you're signed in, go to the settings > general. You may need to correct the url once you're signed in (http://security-shell.com/wp-admin/options-general.php)
- Make sure your site URL is correct in the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)) fields.

Once you save this things may look messy again but you should be able to see your site correctly at the root.

Essentially what appeared to have happened is that you moved your site without telling your database that you moved it.

To not have this happen in the future; make the changes described above first, then move the files.

Hope this helps!